# Python / Spark .map function : Accessing sub list from record

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with the [movieLens](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) dataset and the goal is to map and transform the dataset into a couple informative and readable dataframes before creating a top-10 list of recommendations for every user in the dataset. The dataset also contains the next movieId every user is **going to** watch, which is used to check if the next movieId is present in the top-10 recommendations per user.

So far i've been able to pull it off solo or with the help of some addtional information here on stackoverflow and/or some tutorials. I wrote a simple function with an if/else statement used to map a RDD and if the nextmovie is present in my top-10 list of recommendations it returns 1, else 0.

```
# MOVIE RECOMMENDOR

#All movies, orderd by popularity
allMoviesRDD = movieStatsDF.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect() 
sample: [296, 356, 593, 318, 480, 260, 110, 589, 2571, 527]

#Joined dataframe that im using
+------+---------+--------------------+
|userId|nextmovie|                seen|
+------+---------+--------------------+
|   148|     2629|[2396, 2671, 4306...|
|   471|     4122|[3101, 1645, 2858...|
|   833|      527|[364, 150, 432, 4...|
|  1580|     1196|[7161, 1203, 8610...|
|  1645|       26|[608, 107, 7, 256...|
+------+---------+--------------------+
  root
 |-- userId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- nextmovie: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- seen: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true


# Mapping function
def recommend(record):
    userid, nextmovie, seen = record

    if nextmovie in allMoviesRDD[:10]:
        return 1
    else:            
        return 0

# Call the function     
eval = joinDF.rdd.map(recommend)

# Print succes percentage
print ("Succes% =", 100 * eval.sum() / eval.count())
```

The above is very crude and basic but it works and gives a succes rate of 3.936 %. However, because its possible that a user has already seen one of the movies in the top-10 list, i have to check the top-10 list and the list with movies the user has already seen. If a movieId is present in both lists, i have to remove it from the top-10 recommendations and add the next best movie to top the list off.

I figured this was pretty simple and changed the function to the following:

```
def recommend(record):
    userId, nextmovie, seen = record
    recommendations = allMoviesRDD

    if recommendations[0] in seen:
        recommendations.remove(recommendations[0])

    if recommendations[1] in seen:
        recommendations.remove(recommendations[1])

    if recommendations[2] in seen:
        recommendations.remove(recommendations[2])

    if recommendations[3] in seen:
        recommendations.remove(recommendations[3])

    if recommendations[4] in seen:
        recommendations.remove(recommendations[4])

    # etc, etc... (i tried a for loop but it crashes the kernel)

    if nextmovie in recommendations[:10]:
        return 1
    else:            
        return 0
```

But whatever i try, i cant seem to acces the "seen" list from every record passing the function. I've tried casting it or accessing record[2] and casting that... all to no avail. However i dont get any errors so im assuming the "seen" List within the record is empty. But without debugging i dont really have a clue :(

I've spent hours and hours searching, trying and failing... who can help me understand this damn thing!? :) Thanks alot in advance!